# How to apply style to Listbox Item based on Property value in WPF

Tags: wpf

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
    <Grid Margin="1" x:Name="BackgroundGrid">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding CustomerName}" />  
    <TextBlock  Text="{Binding CustomerId}" />
    </Grid>          
    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CustomerId}" Value="9-3453"><Setter TargetName="BackgroundGrid" Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
    </DataTrigger>                         
    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
    </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate> 
    </ListBox>
```

In the above code, I need to provide DataTrigger's value based on property value instead of hard code the value.

Thanks in advance,
Dinesh

Comment: Try using a MultiBinding with a Value Converter. You can find an example here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/de-DE/729d2ac8-67db-4ab2-856b-8d56a9992bc5/datatrigger-binding-in-value?forum=wpf

Comment: You need to set the Background in the Style, it's a precedence issue

Answer (score 1):

Supposed your DataTrigger's value based on property CustomerNumber. Then you add another property for binding, like this:

```
public bool CustomerIdMatchs
{
    get{
       return CustomerNumber==CustomerId;
    }
}
```

Then you bind CustomerIdMatchs instead of CustomerId, like this:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CustomerIdMatchs}" Value="true">
<Setter TargetName="BackgroundGrid" Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
</DataTrigger>
```